# Facebook App Spam Threshold

Tags: facebook, spam, threshold

What will happen if the app cross the spam threshold? Will be app be taken down and be blacklisted?

Answer (score 4):

It varies from app to app, so no guarantees, but in general you can expect one or all of the following -

- Restriction of access to certain APIs, especially the ones you're maxing out spam reports on.
- Removal from the App Center (if relevant)
- Deletion of the App in question.
- Deletion of all Apps you are an admin of
- Deletion of your Facebook Account